# Automatically deploy saved passwords to clients

Tags: group-policy, domain

Currently, we have a few computers that are not domain-joined.

In the browsers, LastPass is used to automatically fill in the password for a few web applications. Obviously, at this time that is manually set up. However, there's only one account for everyone who uses the computer.

If these are domain joined, how can we leverage Group Policy in order to deploy these saved passwords to all accounts, using either LastPass or just saving the passwords in the browsers or the Windows Credentials Vault?

Copying a file over isn't enough, because the credentials are stored for the account, not in any application files.

Everything I see relating to this is using Group Policies to disable saving passwords in the browser, which is quite the opposite of what we want to do.

Comment: What have you attempted? Individuals accessing shared secrets is a feature of LastPass Enterprise. Import into that.  https://www.lastpass.com/enterprise/sharing

Answer (score 1):

AD has no mechanism to distribute passwords to multiple users in policies directly. It is highly insecure.

With the caveat that sharing an account/password is not a good idea you could write a script to add an account and password to a users password vault and deploy the script in AD policy for a one time run.

There is a secure workflow to distribute transparent user access in an AD domain joined environment.  This works for domain joined applications.

1) Enable SPNEGO authentication in your browsers for the web app (group policy can do this).

2) Enable Kerberos authentication for your web application and target a domain group(s) for authorized users.  Some apps do this natively. IIS hosted apps that use user credential services can be configured to use Kerberos.

3) Add all your domain users to the domain access group.

With this setup access becomes transparent to the users.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have any control over the web application. All we can do is save the password in the browser or an extension which effectively does the same thing. Users should not need to know the password at all (though the password is not a major secret either). Plain text/insecure is OK, we just need the password to be pre-populated at logon. So this would work with the Windows Vault script?

Comment: A script can be used to manipulate the user space vault, yes.  And, AD policy can be used to deploy any given script for each user.

Comment: If the application can take the username and password in post variables (no security really), you could create a shortcut with the embedded values in the url and deploy the shortcut to the user desktop with an AD policy.

Comment: Would the password vault route work for all browsers or just IE? I think IE should work, but it could be the application may not work in it... not sure.

Comment: Vault is IE specific. Each browser is specific. I’m not sure if others are accessible programmatically.

Comment: Well, if you save passwords in Chrome Portable, they turn out to be saved on the computer, not in the Chrome files. In fact, accessing them is "protected" by your Windows password. This leads me to believe they are stored somewhere in the account. Otherwise, one could just copy a config file containing the passwords.